# PHP: How to reorder a two dimensional array

Tags: php

This is how `$myArray` looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [month] => 1
            [atual] => 0.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [month] => 2
            [atual] => 11970.99
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [month] => 3
            [atual] => 2888.00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [month] => 5
            [atual] => 1500.00
        )

)
```

I want to "fill the gaps" of the months. That is, for those months, where we have no data `(4,6,8,9,10,11,12)`, I want the `[atual]` to be zero.

I tried:

```
$novo=array();

for ($i=1; $i <=12 ; $i++) {
    $mes=$myArray[$i-1]['month'];
    $atual=$myArray[$i-1]['atual'];

    if(!$mes){
        $novo[$i]=0;
    } else{
        $novo[$i]=$atual;
    }
};
```

But this is returning:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 0.00
    [2] => 11970.99
    [3] => 2888.00
    [4] => 1500.00
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 0
    [10] => 0
    [11] => 0
    [12] => 0
)
```

Comment: isn't the returning result what you want ?

Comment: No, because I want the index of the array to match the months 1 to 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
$novo=array_fill(1,12,0);

for ($i=1; $i <=12 ; $i++) {
            $mes=$myArray[$i-1]['month'];
            $atual=$myArray[$i-1]['atual'];

            $novo[$mes]=$atual;

};
```

Answer (score 1):

[edit] now i see you have another problem, your `$myArray` indexes aren't matching the months.

```
$myArray( 
    array('month' => 1, 'atual' => 0.00),
    array('month' => 2, 'atual' => 11970.99),
    array('month' => 3, 'atual' => 2888.00),
    array('month' => 5, 'atual' => 1500.00)
)

for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++){
    $novo[$i] = 0;
}

foreach($myArray as $item){
    $novo[$item['month']] = $item['atual'];
}

print_r($novo);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is returning ... [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 1500.00
        ). Although there's no data for April

Comment: ohhh i see your problem, your $myArray indexes aren't matching months. Try this version now. I dont understand if you want a plain array with month as index and atual as value, but if you want a multi index array is simple to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

With this code you get the month 1 in position 1 (not in position 0);
Also you only search in the array one time.
It's not a beautiful solution but...

```
$my_array = array(
array('month'=>3,'actual'=>100)
);

$results =array();
for($i=1;$i<13;$i++){
    $results[$i] = 0;
}

foreach($my_array as $a){
    $results[$a['month']] = $a['actual'];
}
print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

[PHP has several functions that deal with sorting arrays, and here is a comparison of array's sorting functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand your question in the first response. This code should work for you. First we will create a temporary array just to hold the month and the data in an accessible format. Then we create your array :

```
$temp=array();

// Populate the temp array
foreach ($myArray as $row) {
    if (is_array($row) && isset($row["month"])) {
        $temp[$row["month"]] = $row["atual"];
    }
}

// Create novo array
for ($i=0; $i <12 ; $i++) {
    $novo[$i]["month"] = $i+1;
    if (array_key_exists($i+1, $temp)) {
        $novo[$i]['atual'] = $temp[$i+1];
    } else {
        $novo[$i]['atual'] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is returning ...  [4] => Array
        (
            [month] => 4
            [atual] => 1500.00
        ). Although there's no data for April

Comment: I managed to find a solution (see my own answer). In my previous comment, I meant the index 4 of the array was wrong since there was no data for month 4 (April)